# How to use awk to print +3 lines of every nth line starting at a specific line?

Tags: unix, awk

So starting at line 2 I want to print the following 3 lines and do the same thing for every 16th line until the end of my file.  All I have so far is:

```
    awk 'NR % 16 ==2'
```

I'm having trouble in adding the "print the following 3 lines" part.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

with smart counters..

```
$ awk 'NR%16==2{c=4} c&&c--' <(seq 40)
2
3
4
5
18
19
20
21
34
35
36
37
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
awk 'NR>=2 && !((NR-2)%16) {print; getline; print; getline; print}' file
```

Comment: When I try this it only prints the 16th line starting from the 2nd line.  What I was looking for was printing +3 lines starting from the 2nd line and doing the same thing for every 16th line after.  Basically print lines, 2,3,4,5, then 18,19,20,21, then 34,35,36,37....and so on

Comment: Who upvoted this. Next skips all following commands. Maybe you meant getline?

Comment: @e1v1s Sorry, I mixed next and getline. I've changed it. (at)123 Thanks for the hint. It was a typo..

Comment: Better to use `awk 'NR%16==2{x=4}x&&x--'` construct as writing print and getline, especially for a lot of lines, is repetitive and redundant.

Comment: @123 yes, that's true. I'll keep it as it is now to give other user the change to distinguish between karafka's smart and my stupid solution. ;)

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the link! I'll take that into account. Was in kind of a stressful situation at afternoon. I should actually not answer questions at such moments. just wanted to help...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -n '2~16{N;N;N;p}' file
```

Comment: Depending on whether OP wants to only print if all 4 lines are there, then this may not be suitable as it will not print values at the end of the file if it matches say 2 line before then end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{flag=0;count=0}NR%16==2{flag=1;print;next}flag{print;++count}count==3{count=0;flag=0}' <filename>
```

#### Example

`input.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
```

Use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{flag=0;count=0}NR%16==2{flag=1;print;next}flag{print;++count}count==3{count=0;flag=0}' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
4
5
18
19
20
21
```